# Error: response status is 400. The JSON value could not be converted to EmployeeAPI.Models.Tblemployee

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to add Employee using Database first approach.
My tblEmployee.cs class

```
public partial class Tblemployee
{
    public Tblemployee()
    {
        TblEmployeeSalaries = new HashSet<TblEmployeeSalary>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Password { get; set; }
    public string? Ename { get; set; }
    public string? Department { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TblEmployeeSalary> TblEmployeeSalaries { get; set; }
}
```

My TblEmployeeSalary class

```
public partial class TblEmployeeSalary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public long Salary { get; set; }

    public virtual Tblemployee Employee { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Employee Repository

```
   public EmployeeRepository(NewEmployeeContext employeeContext)
   {
       _employeeContext = employeeContext;
   }
   public async Task<Tblemployee> AddEmployee(Tblemployee employee)
   {

       var tblemployee = new Tblemployee
       {
           Email = employee.Email,
           Password = employee.Password,
           Ename = employee.Ename,
           Department = employee.Department
          
       };
  
       var addemployee = await _employeeContext.Tblemployees.AddAsync(tblemployee);
       await _employeeContext.SaveChangesAsync();
       return addemployee.Entity;
   }
```

Employee Controller

```
 private readonly IEmployee _employee;

    public EmployeeController(IEmployee employee)
    {
        _employee = employee;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddEmployee(Tblemployee tblemployee)
    {
        try
        {
    
            if (tblemployee == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var addEmployee = await _employee.AddEmployee(tblemployee);
            return Ok(addEmployee);
        }
        catch
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Error retrieving Data from Database");
        }

    }
```

After running the service, I am getting below error:-

> {   "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
> "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",   "status": 400,
> "traceId": "00-0fd5d65a07cea14fdf89b3c367a64bf7-450f3d5145bcb3a8-00",
> "errors": {
> "tblemployee": [
> "The tblemployee field is required."
> ],
> "$.tblEmployeeSalaries[0].employee": [
> "The JSON value could not be converted to EmployeeAPI.Models.Tblemployee. Path:
> $.tblEmployeeSalaries[0].employee | LineNumber: 11 |
> BytePositionInLine: 26."
> ]   } }

My Request Body as follows:-

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "email": "string",
  "password": "string",
  "ename": "string",
  "department": "string",
  "tblEmployeeSalaries": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "employeeId": 0,
      "salary": 0,
      "employee": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Inspect the request to see the JSON value that it is unable to convert.

Comment: You should provide the json sent in the request.

Comment: could you provide the whole request body?

Comment: Request body updated in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the employee string as I have indicated below. It doesn't match the class definition.

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "email": "string",
  "password": "string",
  "ename": "string",
  "department": "string",
  "tblEmployeeSalaries": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "employeeId": 0,
      "salary": 0,
      "employee": "string"  // Remove this
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: After removing tblEmployeeSalaries, I am able to insert the values, but if I want to insert in both Employee and EmployeeSalary table, how can I do it?

Comment: Did you try just removing the "employee": "string" part of tblEmployeeSalaries, instead of removing the whole thing?

Comment: Do you have a Swagger page? It will show you the schema in JSON form for you under the 'Schemas' section.  (If you are not using Swagger then I suggest you start to.)

Comment: I am using Swagger